# How can I check unreachable subgraph exists when I cut the specific edge?

Tags: algorithm, graph, directed-graph

## What I want to solve:

I want to detect newly created unreachable subgraph(marking nodes that unreachable) in given directed graph if I cut the specific edge.

## The restriction of this problem:

- The given graph is **directed graph** (see useful information below.)
- The number of the nodes are **more than 100,000**.
- The number of the edges are **around 1.5x of nodes**.
- Running time of the solution **should be less than a second**.

## The information that might be useful:

- The given graph was made by **connecting numerous cycles**. And, there are **at least 1 route exists** from any node to other node.
- A few (~ 10%) of the nodes have the branch. **No more than 3 edges** on the node exists in the graph.
- The meaning of "unreachable area" is including "not connected", **but** you can ignore this if you think this is mixing two different problems into one.

## My trials

When I met this problem, I tried in 4-ways but no luck above of them.

1. Find the another path can replace the cut node.

This method is rejected because of running time of method. Currently we use Dijkstra Algorithm for path-find and when I tried this method by putting into job queue, the job queue was flooded in less than an hour.

2. Check level of edges (like packets' Time-To-Live from network.)

```
Search from edge node with given threshold level.
If I met the branch, keep previous level. Otherwise, decrease level.
If level is 0, do nothing.
```

Current temporal solution is this one, but **obviously** this solution ignores a lot of corner cases.

3. Simulate flow network to the graph.

It's simple:

```
Give a threshold(like 100) to every nodes and simulate its flow.
If I met the branch, split number into each branch.
Check the values that is lower than 1.
```

But this method is also rejected because of **Time complexity**.

4. SCC and Topological sorting.

Lastly, I check the Strongly-Connected-Components with Topological orders. (**Of course** I know I used wrong word, see below)

The idea is, topological sorting is **used for DAG**(Directed Acyclic Graph), but If I add some rules(like "If I detect cycle, treat that cycle as a virtual node, recursively", using **SCC**), I can check the **"topological orders"** for general directed graph. If I found the topological orders, this means that there is an area that unreachable. (It's hard to say, think about it with method 3: simulate flow network)

I think this approach is the best one, and might be solve the problem, but I have no ideas about keywords that should I search and learn about it. Same as implementation.

## EDIT

I forgot the explanation of unreachable means. If there is no route from a node(node 'A') to any other node, node 'A' is **"unreachable"**. Initially, at given digraph, there are no unreachable node exists.

In this problem, let's assume that node 1 is the master node. if there is no route from node 1 to node 2, then node 2 is unreachable.

Comment: *"have the branch"*: I don't understand that. Which branch?

Comment: *"job queue was flooded"*: what is a job? Can the queue not hold *all* the nodes? Why do you use Dijkstra's algorithm which is specific for *weighted* graphs? How does weight relate to the detection of a disconnected graph?

Comment: *"marking nodes that unreachable"*: unreachable from where? Do you have a specific node you "look" from? This might mean that potentially almost all nodes become unreachable, which means that marking those will take a time that is linear to those number of nodes.

Comment: @trincot "...nodes have the branch" means there are multiple edges from a node to another node. "Job queue was flooded" means the path-finder is already coded by another people in past, and it works as "job queue". A job is defined as start node and end node. If I enqueue job into job queue, the path-finder will dind the path and put the route into result queue.

Comment: @trincot sorry about confusion. I added some missing condition on article. "unreachable" from node 1, in this problem.

Comment: So, what you want to know is if your graph has a single strongly connected component, you want to make sure that the edge you are removing is not a bridge.
This algorithm should help, remove the edge and if there is more than one SCC then you know the edge was a bridge.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm

Comment: This seems a very long explanation to ask for an algorithm that determines whether a certain edge is a bridge. But, I am confused by the comment that you use a "path-finder" that is already coded. So, do you intend to use it, or not? If you are using it, then what is really the question? If that code does not perform as you want, then do you want to have it reviewed? Or do you want it to be replaced by better code?

Comment: @trincot  I mentioned the "path-finder" for my previous trials. The given graph, and the given problem is not just a single problem. The whole project is a kind of "traffic management". A lot of suggestions like "realtime intersection problem solver", "traffic jam resolver" or "rebalancing vehicle". And I met this problem which shows the vehicle starvation. This question was the generalized question for this forum. The "path-finder" is for a solution for a specific vehicle should go to, which is not appropriated to my problem. This is why I can't say the "path-finder" is totally useless .

Comment: @hbejgel I think I misunderstood about SCC, which can solve my question. I didn't realize that this can directly give draft for current graph status for me. Thanks a lot.